# Appending some value to a list or an array

Tags: c#, list, append

so I am trying to take all the numbers from a list that are less than 5 and I try to put them in another list and print that list. I have no idea how to do that in c#. I will be very grateful if you'd help me. Thank you and here is my code:

```
using System;
namespace exercices
{
   class Hello
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
       int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, };
       int[] b = { };

       for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)

        {
            if (a[i] < 5) 
            {
                b.Append(a[i]);
            }
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: You cannot add item to array, they lenght is constant... Use generic List

Comment: `b = int[] b = a.Where(item => item < 5).ToArray();`

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1. Just check every element

You should use [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) collection in this method. It's possible to convert it to array later, if you need.

```cs
List<int> b = new();

foreach (int element in a)
{
    if (element < 5)
    {
        b.Add(element);
    }
}
```

### Method 2. Use [`Array.FindAll<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findall) method

```cs
int[] b = Array.FindAll(a, element => element < 5);
```

### Method 3. Use LINQ

```cs
int[] b = a.Where(element => element < 5).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
using System;
namespace exercices
{
class Hello
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, };
    int[] b = { };

   for (int i = 0; i < a.Length;i++)
    {
     Int number=a[i];
     if (number < 5)
     b.Insert(i, number);
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid explicit for loops using LINQ: the Where() method returns an IEnumerable object; you can then create an array or a list from the IEnumerable with the corresponding ToArray()/ToList() method, as shown below:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

IEnumerable<int> lessThanFiveElements = a.Where(element => element < 5);
        
int[] lessThanFiveArray = lessThanFiveElements.ToArray();

List<int> lessThanFiveList = lessThanFiveElements.ToList();
```

In case you have a console application, you can then print the resulting array/list with a Console.WriteLine() command, as shown below

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lessThanFiveElements));
```

where I used the string.Join() in order to have comma separated elements, which accepts the separator as a first parameter and any IEnumerable as the second one.